# Is it possible at all to you both with or?

Tags: meaning, grammar, ambiguity

Is it possible to say:
"I am open to ***BOTH***  MSc  ***OR***  Ph.D. positions."?

As I can not possibly have both positions at the same time, using and here seemed a little bit strange to me. I may say "I am open to either an MSc or a Ph.D. position"; However, I got curious about the possibility to say the same thing using both.

Comment: Both...and. Either...or.

Comment: Certainly it's possible to say it.  It's not "correct", however.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just take out the word *both*. It's generally extraneous and definitely extraneous here. Also, use your punctuation consistently.

I am open to M.Sc. or Ph.D. positions.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
do you mean it is grammatically incorrect?
If I insist on using 'both', do I have to use 'and' and say "to both M.Sc. and Ph.D."?

Comment: Please check at the Help Center; answers should be accompanied by linked and attributed supporting references, or if the question is deemed to basic to need them, not given at all.